# slices.Contains is not able to infer types from args

Tags: go

I'm using Go 1.21 and want to create a custom validator function to check if a given value is a valid log level for the `slog` package. I tried

```
import (
    "log/slog"
    "reflect"
    "slices"
)

func IsLogLevel(value interface{}) bool {
    valueType := reflect.TypeOf(value)
    logLevelType := reflect.TypeOf(slog.LevelDebug)

    if valueType != logLevelType {
        return false
    }

    logLevels := []slog.Level{
        slog.LevelDebug,
        slog.LevelInfo,
        slog.LevelWarn,
        slog.LevelError,
    }

    return slices.Contains(logLevels, value)
}
```

but get the compiler error

> S (type []slog.Level) does not satisfy ~[]E compiler(CannotInferTypeArgs)

Does someone know how to fix this?

*Sidenote: Yes, I know, I could write my own contains function but Go 1.21 seems to provide one :)*

Comment: The variable `value` has _static_ type `interface{}`, not type `slog.Level` (which is the element type of the `logLevels` argument), hence the error. Instead of using reflection you should simply type-assert the argument and pass the result of the type assertion to the generic function (in place of `value`).

Comment: sorry, would you mind providing an example? You mean like so? `variable, ok := value.(type)`

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/dmkiJJNwm7Q

Comment: Thanks, I improved your playground example https://go.dev/play/p/iFkCTRZuZJR Feel free to post an answer :)